# Matrix-form derivative and vector-format derivative are same using Alternating least squares (ALS) algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, matrix-decomposition

$W \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$, $H \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$,$Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

$$\min_{W,H}f(W,H) = \|Y-W^T H\|^2_F +\lambda \|W\|^2_F+\lambda \|H\|^2_F$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} = 0 \quad \implies \quad W = (H H^T + \lambda I)^{-1} H Y^T$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial H} = 0 \quad \implies \quad H = (W W^T + \lambda I)^{-1} W Y$$

In this figure (matrix factorization with regularization), I try to use the alternating least squares (ALS) algorithm to get the derivative for **W** when we fix the **H** as constant and for **H** when we fix the **W** as constant, and set the derivative equal to zero, I get the analytical solution for **W** and **H**, but it is matrix form.

Can someone help get the vector-form analytical solution? for example: **W_i** (the ith column of **W**) and **H_i** (the ith column of **H**). Like this: http://bugra.github.io/work/notes/2014-04-19/alternating-least-squares-method-for-collaborative-filtering/

The matrix-format derivatives and vector-format derivatives are same? which one is better?

Hope your help.

Thanks.

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks. I modify my question. Hope this time it is feasible to you.

Comment: learn latex ("edit" and see what I wrote) and your derivation seems good, don't care of the "vector notation" it is the same. now you have to check if $f$ is convex in $(W,H)$ or not, to see if it converges to the global minimum or not. and you should also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization it is the same with $W_{ij} \ge 0, H_{ij} \ge 0$ constraints, and the algorithm is more complicated (but much more useful in signal processing / machine learning)

Comment: Thanks @user1952009   Will learn latex. "matrix notation" is relatively more familiar to me. All the "vector notation" can be expressed in "matrix notation" right? Since a N-dimensional vector can be 1-by -N matrix or N-by-1 matrix.

Comment: one vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be expressed in a matrix notation as $X \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ or $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$. LaTex is very nice. Thanks @user1952009 again.